# enabling CSRF via Angular HttpClientModule, error: TS2552: Cannot find name HttpXsrfInterceptor

Tags: angular, typescript, csrf, angular-http-interceptors, csrf-token

Question comming from a front-end beginner. I would like to add csrf tokens to some of the requests in a frontend app. The application is using Angular in version 12.2.17. I follow instructions from Angular documentation: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClientXsrfModule

In the code I am adding the interceptor as follows:

```js
import {HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule, HttpClientXsrfModule  } from "@angular/common/http";


imports: [
        ...
        HttpClientXsrfModule
    ],
providers: [
         ...
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useExisting: HttpXsrfInterceptor, multi: true }
    ],
```

When I do that, the line with "HttpXsrfInterceptor" is triggering error tooltip in IntelliJ:

> TS2552: Cannot find name  HttpXsrfInterceptor . Did you mean HTTP_INTERCEPTORS ?

What should I change to configure the HttpXsrfInterceptor correctly?

**What I have tried:**

If I try to change the imports line to :

```js
import {HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule, HttpClientXsrfModule, HttpXsrfInterceptor } from "@angular/common/http";
```

Then I am getting another error message from the mentioned line:

> TS2724:  "@angular/common/http"  has no exported member named
>  HttpXsrfInterceptor . Did you mean  HTTP_INTERCEPTORS ?

Comment: AFAIK you only have to add the module to `imports`. No need to add anything to `provides` unless you need custom behavior.

Comment: That was my first try but when I did that, there was no effect and no X-XSRF-TOKEN was  not added to the requests, so I thought to follow the documentation from Angular

Comment: You need to get the cookie from the server before Angular can add the header. Perhaps you need to perform an initial request to get the cookie?

Comment: Also Angular 12 is pretty old and no longer support. There may be bugs.

Comment: @rveed Yep you are very correct. But as you can imagine, upgrading versions in legacy apps its not always so trivial:) Sometimes you have to work with what you get.

Comment: @rvneed the cookie is set. I am able to see it in console and in development tools.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the code which compiled without error is:

```js
import {GlobalHttpInterceptorInterceptor} from "./pathto/myinterceptor";
...

 providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: GlobalHttpInterceptorInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
```

where GlobalHttpInterceptorInterceptor is an interceptor defined as:

```js
@Injectable()
export class GlobalHttpInterceptorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor( 
    private tokenExtractor: HttpXsrfTokenExtractor
  ) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):

    Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
      console.log("global intercept  ");
      const cookieheaderName = 'X-CSRF-TOKEN';
      let csrfToken = this.tokenExtractor.getToken() as string;
      console.log("global csrfToken: " + csrfToken);
      if (csrfToken !== null && !req.headers.has(cookieheaderName)) {
          console.log("global cloning request for : " + csrfToken);
          req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set(cookieheaderName, csrfToken) });
      }
      console.log("global return the handling");

    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```